# Usecases for SNMP Trap

Tags: monitoring, snmp, snmp-trap

I am new to SNMP Traps. My understanding is that SNMP traps are in general used for Network and Device monitoring. I would like to know if it can be used for Application Monitoring. The application in this case would be Web application (war) deployed on Weblogic application server.
If possible, would SNMP traps be a recommended way to monitor above application ? If not, what would be the preferred way to monitor web application.

Answer (score 1):

SNMP for network management (using combination of traps + polling) is a standard mechanism for that type of monitoring.

Furthermore the Weblogic app server provides infrastructure to facilitate this, quoting [WebLogic 12, SNMP agent docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24424/snmpagent.htm#SNMPA114), it can:

- Respond to simple GET requests from an SNMP manager for the current
  value of WebLogic Server MBean attributes. Note: WebLogic Server does not enable SNMP managers to set the values of MBeans or invoke MBean operations. SNMP managers can be used only
  to monitor WebLogic Server.
- Use JMX monitors to poll WebLogic Server MBeans periodically and send notifications to SNMP managers when the MBean attributes change
  in a way that you specify.
- Send notifications to SNMP managers when the Administration Server or any Managed Server starts or shuts down.
- Listen for specific log messages and send notifications to SNMP managers when WebLogic Server generates them.
- Act as a proxy agent that passes requests from an SNMP manager to other (non-WebLogic) SNMP agents (such as an Oracle database agent)
  on the same machine.